# Listfiles() not showing Drive files, only uploaded files

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using a web application account and when I use the function
 `$files = $service->files->listFiles();` 
It shows only the uploaded files by the API, so I can't perform a search or anything related in the Drive I'm accessing. Is it an API problem, a scope problem or anything else? Thanks. Here are the libraries I'm using in the script.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
```

And for the scopes:

```
$client->addScope(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "web application account"?

Comment: Just not a service account, it's the Client ID for web application section in the console.developers for when acquiring the .json for the credentials.

Comment: Try checking the response in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it) and see if you are still getting the same result.